# Why is half my root LVM SSD inaccessible?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, 16.10, lvm

So far as I know, before there was some catastrophic log overflow I had full access to the 500gb. Some crash logs overflowed and generated about 78gb worth of logs in /var/log. I've since deleted that and emptied the trash.

I have no idea if there's a correlation but now I am seeing this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
:~$ df -h
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                           16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                         3.2G  219M  3.0G   7% /run
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root  188G  111G   68G  62% /
tmpfs                          16G  403M   16G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                          16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                     220G  106G  104G  51% /media/SSD2
/dev/sdc2                     473M  130M  319M  29% /boot
/dev/sdc1                     511M  3.6M  508M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sdd1                     1.4T  467G  839G  36% /media/HDD1
/dev/sdb1                     2.7T  2.3T  341G  87% /media/HDD2
tmpfs                         3.2G   52K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are mistaken and that space was never available, since volumes don't shrink on their own.  You probably did not allocate the rest of the space in the vg to the lv when you set it up.  See the output of `pvs`.  If the vg has free space, then you can use `lvresize -r -l 100%FREE vg/root` to expand the volume to use the rest of the free space.  Of course, that means you won't have any free space left to create new volumes or snapshots.

Comment: Ah. Ya that may be the case. I just would have assumed that the LVM partitioning at system install allocated everything and there's no clear way to expand it in GParted. I get `PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  
  /dev/sdc3  kubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  475.96g 253.38g`

Comment: Can I safely expand a live `/` partition with no data loss?

Comment: @Enigma, yes.  If you ever plan on using snapshots or creating more logical volumes though, you may not want to use up all of the space ( and if not, then why use LVM in the first place? ).

Comment: I guess for the benefit of being able to resize partitions in live environments. It was just a new option on the installer that I thought would be interesting to try out. Live snapshots would be handy but I'd rather not use an SSD to store the snapshot - better used for speeding up things that actively use the speeds.

Comment: @Enigma, Resizing partitions in live environments is possible even without LVM. Although, with LVM you don't need to worry about moving partitions which is not possible from live system.